# Not able to figure out how the code can be further optimised

Tags: c++

This problem is from hackerrank and the link is : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-squares  .
  The program below prints the count of numbers that are perfect squares within the given range. However, I get an error of time limit exceeded as the constraints for testcases are `1 < testcase < 100` and for 2 integers in the range are `1 < number 1 < 10^9, 1 < number2 < 10^9` .

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
  int testcase;
  cin>>testcase;          //input testcase
  while(testcase--)
  {
       int number1,number2,count=0;
       cin>>number1>>number2;                 //input the limits
       for(int i=number1;i<=number2;i++) //check for each number within the limits if it is a proper square
        {
            if(sqrt(i)==floor(sqrt(i)))
            count++;
        }

        cout<<count<<endl; //print the total count of numbers that are  perfect square within the limits
    }
return 0;
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to optimize the problem further. As I am not able to figure out how time complexity can be further reduced.

Comment: Question? Timing? Algorithm?

Comment: You'll get an infinite loop if `number1 > number2`

Comment: And yeah, what's the question?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sounds like something from HackerRank.com

Comment: Yes it is a practice problem from hackerrank and I have included the link for it. Somehow I forgot to put the link. Thanks for letting me know!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to code it for you. However :

Instead of testing every number, find the first perfect square in the range. Then, increment by one the square root of the perfect square. That gives you the next perfect square. Repeat until you reach the upper limit.

Expected improvement would be around the order of your numbers. If number1 is 1000, you'll be skipping around a thousand number at each step. That should pass easily.

Answer (score 2):

As the number of squares is exactly the difference
between the square root of the next greater square number of `number1` and square root of biggest square number below `number2`, you can use something like

```
cout << (int) ( floor(sqrt(number2)) - ceil(sqrt(number1)) + 1)
```

Check if number2 >= number1 and swap them otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

is it copy paste code?

You get from input stream `n1` and `n2`, but after that you using `number1` and `number2` which are not initialized.

Comment: No, it isnt a copy paste code. I changed all the variable name before putting it up on stackoverflow to be more readable. And I was forgot to change n1 and n2.Oops my mistake. Sorry

Comment: 10^9 is to large for int

Comment: @VladislavMikitich: It's not too large for a 32-bit `int`.